# Python Logging levels don't seem to be working

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I would like to log info level information to a file and debug level info to the console. I am using `StreamHandlers`, but both `logging.info` and `logging.debug` both log to the console and file. I would like the console to just show `test1` and the file to just show `test`.

```
import logging
import os

rootLogger_file = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger_file.setLevel(logging.INFO)

rootLogger_console = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger_console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('info', "w")

rootLogger_file.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
rootLogger_console.addHandler(consoleHandler)

rootLogger_file.info('test')
rootLogger_console.debug('test1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only creating a single logger with level `DEBUG` and you are adding both handlers to it. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects):

> Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.

```
f = logging.getLogger()
f.setLevel(logging.INFO)

c = logging.getLogger()  # returns the same object as before!
c.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

f is c
# True  # f and c are the same object!

f.level
# 10  # DEBUG
c.level
# 10  # DEBUG
```

Since the one logger you have has level `DEBUG` (which means it also logs INFO and all other levels) and is picked up by both handlers, both messages are shown on the console and in the file. You have to give them different names upon creation:

```
f = logging.getLogger('f')
f.setLevel(logging.INFO)
c = logging.getLogger('c')
c.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# ...
f.info('test')  # logs to file
c.debug('test1') # logs to console
```